# Merging list elements of two lists if unequal length

Tags: r, data.table

I have two lists. List elements are data.tables.

One list contains all Keys:

```
listA <- list(Key1 = data.table(A = rnorm(5), B = rnorm(5), C = rnorm(5)),
              Key2 = data.table(A = rnorm(5), B = rnorm(5), C = rnorm(5)),
              Key3 = data.table(A = rnorm(5), B = rnorm(5), C = rnorm(5)))
```

The other list is a subset with additional information:

```
listB <- list(Key1 = data.table(D = "B"),
              Key2 = data.table(D = "N"))
```

I want to add column D from the tables in listB  to the tables in listA, where the Key is matching. I have tried with:

```
mapply(FUN = function(x, y) x[, D := y[, D]], x = listA, y = listB, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

but this throws the warning.

> Warning message:
>   In mapply(FUN = function(x, y) x[, `:=`(D, y[, D])], x = listA,  :
>     longer argument not a multiple of length of Shorter

In the end it is doing the job, but recycles the D column for the Key not in listB.

How can I achieve that column D is only added for the tables if the Key matches. Or even better to add column D for all tables in listA and if there is no match, then just fill NA in column D in listA. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that if you use `mapply` with vectors or lists of different lenghts, it will repeat the shorter element. Thus, if you have the two lists:

```
mapply(FUN, list(a1, a2, a3), list(b1, b2))
```

Is equivalent to doing (throwing a warning):

```
mapply(FUN, list(a1, a2, a3), list(b1, b2, b1))
```

What you can do to avoid this is create in `listB` the data tables that don't have a matching in `listA`, with a column `D` filled with `NA`'s. Something like:

```
listB[[setdiff(names(listA), names(listB))]] <- data.table(D = NA)

mapply(FUN = function(x, y) x[, D := y[, D]], x = listA, y = listB, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Now it does not throw warnings and you have column `D` from non-matching elements filled with `NA`'s.